# Insert space character in AppleScript filename

Tags: applescript, whitespace

I'm using the date property in Applescript to define a filename with the current year in it, which should be "[YYYY] IDEAz.txt". However, it breaks whenever I insert the space. This works: `property text_file : "~/Dropbox/Notes/" & year of this_date & "IDEAz.txt"`. It yields "2015IDEAz.txt". However, this does not: `property text_file : "/Users/nathanlucy/Dropbox/Notes/" & year of this_date & space & "IDEAz.txt"`. It yields the file "2015" (no extension).

What am I missing here? How should I define the property `text_file` differently so that I can include a space character?

Comment: A side note: **never ever** define paths in property declarations. Properties are evaluated at compile time and persist until the script is recompiled. Under certain circumstances this will never happen and you will get unexpected behavior in case the script is moved or copied to another machine.

Comment: @vadian should I use `set` then?

Comment: Yes, declare the property with a dummy default value and assign the proper value at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1) Explicitly set the year to text:

```
(this_date's year as text)
```

2) Express the concatenation as its own variable:

```
set year_file_name to (this_date's year as text) & space & "IDEAz.txt"
```

Then, use that variable in the property definition.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
property text_file : "/Users/nathanlucy/Dropbox/Notes/" & year of this_date & " IDEAz.txt"
```

?

But I would like to see how you use this path. The result file named with the year only looks like the path has been cut because of the space. And that leads me to a shell script. Maybe you should try

```
property text_file : quoted form of ("/Users/nathanlucy/Dropbox/Notes/" & year of this_date & " IDEAz.txt")
```

Greetings from Michael / Hamburg